# Vuong's Test in Python?

Tags: statistical-significance, python

Does anyone know of a python implementation, or have one to share, of Vuong's Closeness test for non-nested models (Vuong, Q. H. (1989). Likelihood ratio tests for model selection and non-nested hypotheses. Econometrica, 57, 307-333.)?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - I made a related question to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75727494/9963216]) which included my attempt at an implementation in Python.